# Django: cómo crear una acción de admin con valores ingresados por el usuario

Tags: python, django

Al admin del model Partido (partidos de fútbol) quiero agregarle una acción que me permita cambiar la fecha de varios partidos a las vez usando un timedelta. El timedelta lo ingresaría el usuario una vez seleccionados los partidos a cambiar.

Pongo un ejemplo: en el admin selecciono tres partidos (uno se jugaba el 05/10/2018 y los otros dos el 12/10/2018), elijo la acción "Cambiar delta" del menú desplegable, esto me lleva a otra página donde ingreso los días de retraso/adelanto (por ejemplo, 3 días), le doy confirmar y me regresa a la lista de partidos. Ahora las fechas deberían ser 08/10/2018 para el primero y 15/10/2018 para el segundo.

Sé que esto se hace con acciones con página intermedia, pero por más que he buscado, nada me funciona. Logro desplegar la página donde ingreso el delta, pero luego la función de la acción no recibe ningún dato.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

Comment: Te dejo la documentación para crear acciones personalizadas en Django 2.1, te ayudaría un poco más si me dices las versiones de Django y Python con las que trabajas, así como el `Model Partido`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Comment: Bienvenido al sito Fico. !!! te doy la bienvenida y te invito a que realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!. Es importante modifiques el formato de tu pregunta agregando lo que has tratado o investigado, saludos.